# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"При желании(,) я мог бы и пешком пройтись". Нужна ли тут запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, запятая не нужна. При желании - обычное обстоятельство. Его можно заменить придаточным условным, ср.: Если бы я пожелал, мог бы и пешком пройтись.